# How to create loader animation like Ajio mobile app in flutter. Below is video of loader

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

Loader link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/15DvTAfyfdBuYmCZuo63tPwi7oX5XAd3i/view?usp=sharing

I want to create this using flutter, dart.

If it can be done without any third party it would a more better.

Any help accepted!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating animation in flutter, You need to create a gif file or lottie file and load it using a Image widget, in order to show it in flutter.

Comment: I wanted to integrate only using flutter I have no idea for other design tools not even the basic idea. So it will be helpful if you suggest something better...

Thanks!

Comment: you can use switch animation and use it to transform animation between two widgets and once it's finished write the animation reverse and forward animation in order to give looping effect. this will need 2 images which you want to transition into.

Comment: But I don't think it will go like shirt is converting into jeans, it will show like shirt is fading (may be) and jeans is appearing.

Please see video and let me know if we can create exactly the same in flutter or not!

Comment: it's a gif file, create one and load it for showing loading that's exactly what ajio is also doing, no special code needed.

Comment: not looking for gif integration I already have that but now I wanted to create such loader and other animations too for my app.

Answer (score 0):

Just Create a Gif Of Your Loader and show it in alert Dialog it will be easy.
or you can create your own animations Using rive and then show it in FLutter

To Create Rive Animation
https://rive.app/

Tutorial to use it
https://medium.com/flutter-community/taking-flutter-animations-a-step-ahead-with-rive-80adea69c7e

create a Rive animation and show it as a Loader.

Comment: I am only looking for a flutter native code to animate in such a way .